# Align Navbar menu to the middle of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a brand image in the center of the navbar and one menu on either side of it. I want to align **both menus to the image** (menu on the right side of the image is left aligned and vise versa). I managed this on the right menu but I can't align the menu on the left side.

What I have right now, looks good on *large screens* but does not condense properly on a *smaller screen* (on the left side, the right is correct).

**CSS**

```
.navbar{
  background-color: white;
  border: 0px;
  height: 200px;
}

.navbar-middle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.navbar-left {
  padding-right: 10%;
  padding-top: 90px;
  width: 50%;

}

.navbar-right {
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-top: 90px;
  width: 50%;
}

.navbar-left li {
  padding-left: 20%;
}

.navbar-right li {
  padding-left: 15%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Our Vision</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">The Team</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav navbar-middle">
  <li><img src="200.jpg"></li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352519/align-navbar-menu-to-the-middle-of-the-page/35352768#35352768) and Run the code snippet in Full page mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are after something like this

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.navbar{
  background-color: white;
  border: 0px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.navbar-left {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.navbar-middle {
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.navbar-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.navbar-left li {
  margin-left: 20px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.navbar-right li {
  margin-right: 20px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
  <li><a class="pull-right" href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Our Vision</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">The Team</a></li>
</ul>

<img class="nav navbar-middle" src="https://placehold.it/200x100/894567/ffffff?text=Logo">

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very close to what I was looking for! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see from inspecting the elements, your three `ul` seem to be overlapping.

So I changed the widths of the `navbar-left` and `navbar-right` classes to 45% each and added a width specification for the image, i.e. `img src="200.jpg" size=10%`.

From what I can tell, your left `ul` looked to be right-aligned not because of `class="pull-right"` but because of your `.navbar-left li { padding-left: 20%; }`. You can do the same for your `navbar-right`, i.e. `.navbar-right li { padding-right: 20%; }`.

This is the result: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMreKN. Not sure if it is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option:   [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmulder5/jmof8bww/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
      <li><a class="pull-right" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Our Vision</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">The Team</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-middle">
      <li><img src="200.jpg"></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    background-color: gray;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
}
.nav {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: initial;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 75px;
}
.navbar-left, .navbar-right {
    width: 45%;
}
.navbar-middle {
    width: 10%;
}
```

Comment: It's a slightly simpler solution without using flex.  I don't know if this is what you're looking for...